# How do I set part of a flask url to a python variable

Tags: python, flask

I was just wondering how to set one part of a python Flask web address to a python variable.

**Python code**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<variable>')
def test(variable):
    test = variable
    return("Hello World!!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: print part of the route in python

Comment: Your view function does it already `print(variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what you mean but heres some code using dynamic urls with flask

```
@app.route('/study_type/')
@app.route('/study_type/<study>')
def study_type(study=None):
    if study == '1':
        return render_template('1.html')
    elif study == '2':
        return render_template('2.html')
    else:
        return render_template('study_type.html')
```

In this this example is a user goes to `/study_type/1` they get redirected to `1.html`. If they just hit `/study_type` they get redirected to `study_type.html`. You can pass in the dynamic url value in the route/view function

You can print out the variable using (in your example):

```
return("Hello World!! " + variable)
```

or

```
print(variable)
```

Or you can return it to the template:

```
if study == '1':
    return render_template('1.html', study_no=study)
```

and then it will be available in your jinja template as `study_no`

Comment: Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i follow your question completely but if you are just trying to pass a variable through from the route to the function. There are some examples here http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#url-converters

Depending on the type of variable you can enter that in the route. e.g

```
@app.route('/user/id/<int:user_id>')
def profile(user_id):
    pass
```